# Spring MVC controller JSON date serialization during testing

Tags: json, unit-testing, spring-mvc, mockito

I'm writing unit tests for Spring MVC 4.2.x REST controllers and have an issue with dates serialized by Jackson (2.6.x). While running the application the dates (`java.util.Date`) are serialized in the format `yyyy-MM-dd` by default (no extra configuration), which is what I want.

However during tests the dates are serialized as timestamps for an unknown reason.

Here's some sample code for the test class:

```
public class OrderControllerTest {

    @Mock
    private OrderService service;

    @InjectMocks
    private OrderController controller;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    private List<Order> orders = new ArrayList<>();

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(controller).build();
        // Initialize dummy order list
        orders.add(...);
        orders.add(...);
        orders.add(...);
    }

    @Test
    public void list() throws Exception {
        // Stub the service find method
        when(service.find(asOfDate, null)).thenReturn(orders);

        // Run the controller and check the result
        MvcResult result =
            mockMvc
                .perform(get("/admin/order/"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().contentType(TestUtil.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].startDate", is(SOME_DATE)))
                .andReturn();

        System.out.println(result.getResponse().getContentAsString());
    }
```

So here I see that the dates returned are all timestamps.

Surefire output:

```
Expected: is <Thu Jan 01 00:00:00 CET 2015>
     but: was <1420066800000L>
```

Am I missing something? Why is the default serialization format different for running the application and for running tests?

Comment: Are you sure Jackson was not customized in our configuration classes/files? By default it serializes dates as numbers, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Nothing that I could find in the code. `jackson-databind` is simply added to the `pom.xml`, that's it.

Comment: How did you solve this?

Comment: Hi, I solved using `.andExpect(jsonPath("$.publishDate", Matchers.is(docFound.getPublishDate().getTime())));`. Maybe this can help someone.